# Error in building and running Xamarin iOs application in visual studio 2015 preview

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am the newbie in **Xamarin Cross Platform development**. I am using **Visual Studio 2015 Preview** for development. I created the new solution for mobile app and it is working correct for both Droid and Windows phone. But after successful connection with iOs Build host I got the error when I build the iOs App like -

**Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous build version of your project.Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.**

And also when I click on View iOS Simulator I got build host error.
Error: Build version problem. it will show the build version problem.

Please tell me the solution for this.

Comment: I assume you tried rebuilding?

Comment: Actually, after building first time, I still got the same error.

Comment: Sounds like a product defect, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17796/xamarin-ios-does-not-support-running-or-debugging-the-previous-built-version-of-your-project which you need to wait for a Xamarin response.

Comment: I am trying this for 5 days, but got same error. Kind of irritating process. Did Xamarin support gives as quick answer or we have to wait for more time.

Comment: Well, you _ARE_ using VS 2015 **PREVIEW**. You may need to be patient. Or revert to a stable version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

### Most common cause of those symptoms

The most likely cause of this issue is the following known bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25811

#### Explanation

The problem in that bug is that the Xamarin.Forms template is using a bad default setting for the iOS project in Visual Studio's configuration manager.

The configuration manager works by telling Visual Studio which projects you want to be built and/or deployed at the same time in the configuration you're using at the time.

So for example; when you build your Android project in Forms, the configuration manager makes sure that the shared project is included; otherwise it wouldn't work, or you'd have to build it separately or etc. etc. (i.e. a real pain.)

Normally, Visual Studio doesn't have a way to automatically "know" which project(s) you want to include in all your configurations; you'd have to tell it to include (some library) with (some app); etc. manually.

#### How to fix it

Screencast: http://www.screencast.com/t/zLoQOpEn

1. Go to "Build -> Configuration Manager"
2. Select the configuration(s) you wish to adjust, (e.g. Debug | iPhoneSimulator, Release | iPhone)
3. Make sure your shared library project(s) are included with the platform-specific configurations. (You can ignore the greyed-out 'Deploy' checkboxes, those are handled automatically)

#### Why this is a bug

So this isn't a bug in that the configuration manager isn't working correctly for iOS projects, but that the Forms template is using a bad default setting for the iOS projects when you create a new app. It should "know" to include the shared project in the iOS configurations by default.